# exclude shortcode content from cache - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, wordpress-theming

I made a shortcode that returns the news on homepage.
I have to show the relevant news for the actual date. If the news is older, that it will show the next one.
The problem is that the page is cached and my news shortcode content also, and the users see an outdated news.

My code is in `footer.php` and create a `div` with all the informations I need, then with a litte js script I use it's content in my Home-Page.

There is a way to exlude only this function/shortocode from cache?

This is my code in `functions.php`

```
global $news;
$today = date('d-m-Y');

$args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'news'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$ids = array();
$dates = array();

if($query->have_posts()){
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        array_push($dates,get_field('end_date'));
        array_push($ids,get_the_ID());
    endwhile;
}
function getClosestEventID($date, array $dates, $last, $ids) {
    $interval               = array();
    $now                    = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    foreach ($dates as $d) {
        // strtotime often has problems with d/m/y so we use d-m-y
        $d = str_replace("/", "-", $d);
        $dateTime           = strtotime($date);
        $toTime             = strtotime($d);
        if (strtotime($d) < $now) { continue 1; }
        if ($toTime < $dateTime) { continue 1; }
        $interval[$d]       = abs($dateTime - $toTime);
    }

    if (!count($interval)) {
        return $last;
    }

    asort($interval);
    $closest                = key($interval);

    $id_key = array_search(str_replace("-", "/", $closest), $dates);
    return $ids[$id_key];
}

$nearestEventID = getClosestEventID($today, $dates, end($ids), $ids);

echo  '<div class="last-event" style="display: none;">'
    . '<span class="event-title">' . get_the_title($nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '<span class="event-content">' . get_the_content($nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '<span class="event-place">' . get_field('ort', $nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '<span class="event-start-date">' . get_field('start_date', $nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '<span class="event-end-date">' . get_field('end_date', $nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '<span class="event-discipline">' . get_field('discipline', $nearestEventID) . '</span>'
    . '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax to load these kind of dynamic blocks on cached pages.
[Ajax Example](https://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/)
(make sure to add the function with _nopriv too, in order for not logged in users to see the block).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadNews();
});

function loadNews() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, // or example_ajax_obj.ajaxurl if using on frontend
        data: {
            'action': 'load_news',
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // output the response into the newsblock
            $("#newsblock").html(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  
}
```

your ajax function could basically contain copy/paste of your current code to output the news. You can even use an interval to update the block every minute or so, while the user is on the page:
[setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)